# Learning rate and memory of Least Mean Square algorithm

Tags: neural-network, algorithms

I am studying neural networks.

> The smaller we make the learning rate, the longer the memory span over which the LMS algorithm remembers past data will be. (Section 3.5(page 103) of Simon Hykin's "Neural Network and Learning Machines":)

I don't understand why this is the case. Could someone explain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the LMS algorithm, but for neural networks it kind of works the same; if you trained a network to output 1 when given 0, and suddenly say 'no, you should actually output 0' with learning rate 0.1. The network will still 'remember' previous data, as it takes a while to converge to the new training data.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the **weight update formula** your model uses.

### $W_{n+1} = W_n - \mu\nabla\epsilon[n]$,

$\mu$ is the learning rate, and we multiply it with the change we want to do. Obviously, the smaller the learning rate you have, the less update you make, and thus the "longer" the model converges and also the "longer" the model remembers its previous states.

Think like this, if you set the learning rate to 0, you learn nothing and your parameters are never updated.